# Is phpseclib's sftp put command synchronous?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I'm doing a `put`, then removing the file, i.e.

```
$sftp->put($filename_dest, $filename, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
unlink($filename);
```

Is this safe, or is `put` asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's synchronous. Under the hood it basically just does a while loop

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.14/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L2011

`$size` is defined as the size of the local file:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.14/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L1990

`$sent` starts off at 0 and is incremented by the size of the data that's being sent over during each loop.

Eventually, the amount of sent data will meet (or exceed) the size of the file and the whole loop will break.